# Selection of an a specific <li> in nested unordered lists

Tags: jquery, select, nested, unordered

would like to select all list elements that *do not* have a nested list under them (could be in any order, so next necessary the first or last).

In the case below it would be the one that reads:

```
<li>Main Item Three</li>
```

I'm able to select those list elements that *do* have a nested list:

```
$('ul.location_list li:has(ul)')
```

Figured I could use something like:

```
$('ul.location_list li:not(ul)')
```

But no dice. Thoughts?

```
<li>Main Item Three</li>

<ul class="location_list">
   <li>Main Item One
      <ul>
         <li>Sub-Item One A</li>
         <li>Sub-Item One B</li>
         <li>Sub-Item One B</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Main Item Two
      <ul>
         <li>Sub-Item Two A</li>
         <li>Sub-Item Two B</li>
         <li>Sub-Item Two B</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Main Item Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('ul.location_list>li:not(:has(ul))')`

(untested :)

Comment: Tried `$("ul.location_list li:not(:contains(ul))").css('color','red');` and makes all the `<li>` tags red. It should just make the very last on red. So, no joy, but thanks.

Comment: how about `$('ul.location_list li:not(:has(>ul))')` ?  Theres further discussion here: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: So close. It also colors the nested `<li>`'s because there are no `<ul>`'s below them either. Working on some way of determining first child of the top `ul`

Comment: ahha!  then `$('ul.location_list>li:not(:has(>ul))')` should only select the direct li children of the top level ul.location_list.  See child selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Bingo! BTW, the `>` is not need before the `ul` in the parens. See your solution: http://sandbox.highsitetest.com/unordered_list_turndowns.html